# Script to make the x red button kill the app

Tags: macos, applications, applescript, script

Quick background: new mac, long time windows user; not scared by linux and scripts.

I am currently using [RedQuits](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/39814/redquits) to make the x red button quit de app, not just close the window.

It is a great program, but has one small problem (for me): one can not select which apps should maintain the default behavior (x close the window, not the app).

So i found a very old (2006) app called [Stoplight](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/26669-stoplight-11-released/) that does exactly what i want: select which programs should not be affected.

Unfortunately, Stoplight does not work anymore.

So, i tried to see what the script does (it's a .bundle), but looks like it's compiled.

To the questions:

- is there a way to decompile the script, so i can make it work again?
- if not, anyone have an idea about how to make a whitelist of apps that should not be closed by RedQuits?
- again, if not, where should i start to build my own script to intercept the signal that closes the windows and make it kill the app?
- any other hints are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If the app has a single window then the red button will quit the app, if it has multiple then it won't

Comment: @Mark yes, i've read about this feature. that is why i need to implement my own way to deal with apps and windows

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it changed the question into something for which answers will be quite different than for your initial question. Can you please add a new question to get answers on how to turn your script into an always-running service?